# Scrapy: extract weblinks from two different types of posts

Tags: scrapy

The target webpage is [here](http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org/jobseeker/search/results/?keywords=pathologist&t731=&t732=&t735=&max=100&site_id=536&search=), in which there are two types of posts:

The weblink of an **in-house** post is in the following html code:

```
<a class="ga_job" href="/jobseeker/job/26930563/blablabla">
```

The weblink of an **External post** is in different html code:

```
<a class="ga_job" onclick="window.open('http://www.indeed.com/rc/blablalbla','_blank');return false;" href="#">
```

What I am trying to achieve is: if @href contains a legitimate weblink (for in-house posts), I will use the following code to get the weblink:

```
il.add_xpath('web_url', 'concat("http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org", .//a[@class="ga_job"]/@href)')
```

If @href contains only a "#" (for external posts), I will use the following code for weblink:

```
il.add_xpath('web_url', 'substring-before(substring-after(.//a[@class="ga_job"]/@onclick, "("),"&qd=")')
```

I tried if...else codes as following, which don't work:

```
for site in sites:
        il = CAPjobsItemLoader(response=response, selector=site)
        il.add_xpath('web_url', './/a[@class="ga_job"]/@href')   #Get the @href
        HREF_value = il.get_collected_values('web_url')[0]
        if '#' in HREF_value:
            il.add_xpath('web_url', 'substring-before(substring-after(.//a[@class="ga_job"]/@onclick, "("),"&qd=")')
        else:
            il.add_xpath('web_url', 'concat("http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org", .//a[@class="ga_job"]/@href)') 

        yield il.load_item()
```

The results I got for web_url are just @href (a weblink for in-house posts or a '#' for external posts).  The if...else command doesn't work.

Comment: I figured out a solution by using two attributes together (It happened more than once that I found a solution shortly after posting my questions here.) See below

Answer (score 0):

My problem can be solved by using two attributes together:

```
il.add_xpath('web_url', 'substring-before(substring-after(.//a[@class="ga_job" and @href="#"]/@onclick, "(\'"),"&qd=")')
il.add_xpath('web_url', 'concat("http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org", .//a[@class="ga_job"]/@href)')
```